# Young girl becomes old in the toilet of an airplane

Tags: science-fiction, identify-this-movie

**Synopsis:**

There is a young girl who hides in the toilet of an airplane. When the airplane lands, we see that she becomes an old woman. At the end of the movie, there were airplanes coming from the past and I think they blast an atom bomb.

**Language:** English

**Country:** Most likely USA

**Time-frame:** ~ last 10 years (watched in)

**Genre:** It seems like it is a kind of a time-travel movie.

**Not these movies:** Millennium, The Langoliers

Comment: Was it possibly Millenium http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097883/ ?

Comment: @DustinDavis: Worth whacking down as an answer and deleting if the OP says no.

Comment: @DustinDavis: I could not be sure if this is the movie. I will check further.

Comment: @DustinDavis: I watched Millennium. Not this one. I think it might be newer than this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: The Triangle (2005) - Pic 01]

[**The Triangle** (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0452573)

From [tv.com](http://www.tv.com/shows/the-triangle/), here's a synopsis:

> **A ragtag team of scientists, led by billionaire Eric Benirall**, attempts to discover what in **the Bermuda Triangle** is causing
>   Benirall's cargo ships to disappear.

[image: The Triangle (2005) - Pic 02]
[image: The Triangle (2005) - Pic 03]

Another [website](http://www.scififreaksite.com/triangle.html) reveals details of the crash:

> **A passenger plane crashes in the triangle** and the rescue vessels find the plane on the  sea bed, covered with 50 years worth of corrosion on barnacles.
>
> At the same time and place, they find torpedo planes from the 50s in almost perfect 
>   condition.
>
> **There is also a little girl survivor in the toilet, a 6 year-old in the body of a 60 year old**.

It's a 3-part mini-series. Watch the scene where the girl hides in the plane's lavatory [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZIQj-RD7FM&t=42m49s). Shortly after, you'll see those "old planes" make a dramatic entrance as well.

Go [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZIQj-RD7FM&t=57m20s) for the scene where divers rescue the little girl.

One more thing. The series doesn't end quite the way you've described it. But don't worry, I won't spoil it for you :-)

<sup>*~ Screenshots from [Centropoholics.com](http://www.centropoholics.com/tv/TheTriangle/gallery.html?category=1) and [NAVER](http://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=gingoba&logNo=80063382197&redirect=Dlog&widgetTypeCall=true)*</sup>

Comment: Yes! This is it! I thought it was a movie. You even found out that it is not. You are really good at this. What is your secret? :)

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry it took so long to track down :-)